# writeToParcel() - передать short значение

Tags: android, android-parcelable

В классе `Parcel` нет метода для записи `short`, как мне записать поля класса у которых тип short? через `writeInt()`?

Comment: почему бы и нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас примитив `short`, то проще через [writeInt()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeInt(int)), при чтении привести обратно.

Если у вас объект `Short`, то можно использовать [writeValue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeValue(java.lang.Object)), он умеет:

> void writeValue (Object v)
>
> Flatten a generic object in to a parcel. The given Object value may currently be one of the following types:
>
> - null
> - String
> - Byte
> - Short
> - ....

Answer (score 0):

Как альтернативу способу указанному @tse можно использовать `writeBundle()`, где в `Bundle` пакуется `short` через `putShort()`